# Number of polygons in a 3D object and the rendering workload?

Tags: graphics, 3d, game-engine

Is there any relation (preferably an equation) between the number of polygons in a 3D object and the rendering workload? I want to see how much the rendering workload would be increased if for instance the number of polygons doubles.

Comment: Well, I mean working calculations. I want to see how much overhead (for GPU, CPU, memory,...) would be increased. Actually I want to conclude the energy usage of the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you define 'workload'? – Erno yesterday
>
> Well, I mean working
> calculations. I want to see how much overhead (for GPU, CPU,
> memory,...) would be increased. Actually I want to conclude the energy
> usage of the device – user1196937 2 hours ago

If that is the actual question, a comparison of energy usage:

You will have to pick specific configurations and test those. Energy usage is very different from GPU to GPU and machine to machine.

Some GPU manufactures give very detailed information on the performance of their processors but when you want to compare those you will need an actual machine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no clear connection between the arbitrary number of polygons and the mythical "workload".

See the following samples:

1. You render a cube with 6 faces composed of 12 triangles. You get, say, 1000fps (without vsync). When you tesselate the cube into 120 triangles, most likely the fps counter remains 1000.
2. You render a single fullscreen-sized quad with a heavy fragment shader with a lot of calculation. You get 0.5fps (or more, but I hope you get the point).
3. Another extreme. You are rendering a thousand of similar cubes, each with different texture. The rendering state change will take most of the time, not the actual rendering.

So, polygons may have different screen area and they may be rendered  not within a single primitive. If you're talking about one big vertex array with a large number of polygons, then for some certain scenarios the performance change must be something like linear. "Something" because the videocard and the drivers are clipping the invisible polys and perfrom the early-out tests for each pixel being rendered.